# Suggest a good method name for "running year"

Tags: ruby, methods, refactoring, naming

Please help to come with a nice name for a method. Actually it is a scope that defines limit on date. This limit is from today and 365 days to the past, to the same day in past basically. So this is kind of rolling year I would say.

This method is currently named #in_last_year. But I don't like it. It can be understand as if it is only returning the previous year, like if today is 2013 it would only return dates in 2012, but actually it can return yesterday or a day a week ago that happens in 2013.

It is used in a faking(seeding) tool. And the usage looks like:

```
Faker::Date.in_last_year
```

I came with names like "in_running_year", "in_ongoing_year". They seem ok for me, but maybe there are some known term for such entity, probably in finance world.

Comment: For no real reason at all: `Faker::Date.continuous_preceding_year`

Comment: It's a good question, but perhaps not best for SO. This may be better served in codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Out of interest, what happens in your method, when the date object represents `29 Feb 2012` (and the current date is e.g. `24 Sep 2013`)?

Comment: `within_last?(365.days)`

Comment: *"There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things."* -- Phil Karlton

Comment: dates_when_donna_who_turns_34_tomorrow_was_33

Answer (score 2):

How about `dates_to.same_day.next_year` or `dates_from.same_day.last_year`

Then you can have modifier words like week, month, or decade, etc.